# What causes this program to segmentation fault?

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, sizeof

I am attempting to calculate the size of pushed data onto the stack. When attempting this I receive a segmentation fault. My objective is to point `ebp` into `esp` before `push`ing any data onto the stack. After I push data onto the stack I am measuring the size of said data in bytes  `ebp - esp` and storing in `ebx` and printing to stdout using `printf`.

For example:

```
; compile with:
; nasm -f elf test.asm && gcc -m32 -o test test.o
section .text
global  main
extern printf

main:
    ; set the frame pointer to the beginning of the stack before-
    ; data is pushed.
    push  ebp
    mov   ebp, esp

    push  ebx
    push  0x00       ; <- null terminating byte/string truncation
    push  0x64636261 ; <- data

    mov   ebx, ebp
    sub   ebx, esp   ; start of stack - end of stack  = sizeof(data) stored in ebx

    push  ebx
    push  format_str
    call  printf
    add   esp, 8

    pop   ebp
    pop   ebx
    ret

section .data
format_str db "%s", 2, 0
```

When compiling this code I receive the output:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Expected output:

```
5
```

Comment: I guess you want `%d`...

Comment: Sorry that was a accident it seg faults with %d also.

Comment: It's considered bad form to modify questions in such a way that answers are invalidated. By all means make a note at the end that a suggestion doesn't work, but wholesale changes are not a good idea.

Comment: Your string data is never removed from the stack. You are missing a `mov   esp, ebp`.

Comment: My apologies, was a mistake on my part. Still it doesn't fix the segmentation fault unfortunately. Any ideas?

Comment: @Jester, isn't that done by the `add esp, 8`?

Comment: That just removes the `push ebx` and the `push format_str`. The ` push  0x64636261` and `push  0x00` are still on the stack. Use `add esp, 16` instead.

Comment: Jester your answer worked. It outputs 12 instead of 5 any idea why?

Comment: `12` is correct. You pushed 3 things, 4 bytes each. `ebx` is 4 bytes too, and `push 0x00` will push 4 zeroes not one.

Comment: Does the stack decrement by the amount of bytes pushed? Or does the stack decrement by 4 from each `push` instruction?

Comment: asd_2323, the stack pointer is a byte address so will move by the number of bytes you push. And, provided you're pushing a 4-byte/32-bit value (like `ebx`), it will move by four bytes. If you pushed a quadword, it would move by more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a start, items should be popped in the *reverse* order to which they were pushed, if you want them back in their original registers. What you have here (with irrelevant lines removed):

```
push ebp
push ebx
pop ebp
pop ebx
```

will not restore `ebp` to its previous value, and this is *very* likely to cause problems moving up through the stack frames.

---

Additionally, you may be better off following the normal practice of restoring `esp` from `ebp` rather than blindly adding eight. That would be something like this at the end:

```
; add esp, 8 ; not the normal way.
mov   esp, ebp
pop   ebp
```

Doing it this way removes the need for you to manually calculate how many bytes you need to take off the stack, a calculation that you actually got wrong since you didn't take into account everything you pushed.

---

And, finally, *before* you do that, you have to make sure the `esp` is in the right place so that the `pop ebp` will work. That means popping everything you pushed (other than `ebp` itself). Since you pushed (after `ebp`) `ebx`, `0x00000000`, `0c64636261`, `ebx`, and `format_str`, you should make sure all of those are off the stack before attempting to pop `ebp`.

Taking all that into account gives you something like:

```
main:
    push  ebp
    mov   ebp, esp

    push  ebx           ; (+1)
    push  0x00          ; (+2)
    push  0x64636261    ; (+3)

    mov   ebx, ebp
    sub   ebx, esp

    push  ebx           ; (+4)
    push  format_str    ; (+5)
    call  printf
    add   esp, 16       ; (-5, -4, -3, -2)
    pop   ebx           ; (-1)

    mov   esp, ebp
    pop   ebp
    ret
```

Each of those `(+N)` comments represent a 32-bit value that has been pushed on the stack, and the `(-N)` comments indicate which instructions reverse those pushes. The `add esp, 16` reverses four of them (at four bytes apiece), and is done that way since we don't care what happens to those items. That leaves the final `pop` to recover the original `ebx` (which we *do* care about).

That final reload of `esp` is, I think, unnecessary in this case since it's been restored to the correct value by previous steps. Whether you leave it in for prolog/epilog consistency is up to you.

Comment: The code still seg faults after making this modification.

Comment: `pop ebx` will not work because there is a bunch of stuff in the way.

Comment: And now you forgot the `format_str` and you got the comment for `0x00` and the `0x64636261` swapped :D

Comment: Thanks, @Jester, have now fixed this.

Comment: Looks good. An alternative would be to not use `ebx` but some caller-saved register such as `edx` and then the whole mess could be reduced.

Comment: could you explain in a bit more detail what `sub esp, 16` is doing and why @paxdiablo?

Comment: For instance if there were more `push` instructions would I have to follow the same sequence you provided to increment the stack pointer?

Comment: @asd_2323: done (and it's `add` rather than `sub`, by the way). And, yes, had you pushed a different number of things, the pops (and/or direct `esp` manipulations)  would also have to adjust.

Comment: So in essence each `push` instruction decrements `esp` by 4?

Comment: asd_2323: each of *your* `push` instructions, yes. However, were you to do something like `push ax` (in x86 or x64), only two bytes would be pushed. It depends on *what* you push, something that's limited by the architecture as well (for example, I don't *think* you can push four bytes on x64, though I haven't looked into it closely).

Comment: The only nitpick is that the call to `printf` doesn't conform to the more modern Linux i386 System V ABI which would require 16 byte alignment at the point of the `printf` function call. I think it is misaligned by 4 bytes.

Comment: `mov   esp, ebp` is pointless here; for `pop ebx` to restore the right thing, ESP has to already be pointing at the saved EBX which you know is right below the saved EBP.  GCC might use `mov ebx, [ebp-4]` / `leave` (leave includes mov esp, ebp) or `add esp,16` / `pop ebx`/`pop ebp`.

Comment: Peter, I covered that in my final paragraph, I just left it in as unoptimised epilog code.